# Change a flag in database to show someone is "online" but it's not working

Tags: mysql, linux, php

Here is a little breakdown of whats going on

The biggest problem I have right now is, in login.php, it is supposed
to change a flag in the database to show a person is online.

```
if($table=='chatmodels'){
              $sql="update ".$table." set loginStatus=1 where user=".$id['user'];
$upd=mysql_query($sql);
```

It should change 'chatmodels.loginStatus' to equal 1 once a person
successfully logs in, but it doesn't work. It used to work.

I'm pretty sure the I have something wrong in the database configuration.

Here is a screenshot of my database
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcaII.jpg

Comment: Migrated because this appears to be a code issue, and not a database issue.

Comment: See this question for a continuance of this problem: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584137/change-a-flag-in-database-to-show-someone-is-online-but-its-not-working

Answer (score 3):

From the screen shot, I see that the `chatmodels` table resides in the `qoc1` database.

Since you are using php, you need to do one of two things:

Option 1 : Use [mysql_select_db](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) as follows:

`mysql_select_db('qoc1');` before calling for the update query

```
if($table=='chatmodels'){ 
          mysql_select_db('qoc1');
          $sql="update ".$table." set loginStatus=1 where user=".$id['user']; 
$upd=mysql_query($sql);
```

Option 2 : Put `qoc1` into the query itself:

```
if($table=='chatmodels'){ 
          $sql="update qoc1.".$table." set loginStatus=1 where user=".$id['user']; 
$upd=mysql_query($sql);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Other things to remember

- If the table is MyISAM, it should run immediately
- If the table is InnoDB, make sure autocommit = 1

**UPDATE 2011-12-15 15:28 EDT**

Try putting `'or die'` after the `$upd=mysql_query($sql);` and see what mysql-based error message comes back

Comment: The database is referenced in a configuration file actually, but I also tried
calling the database in both examples you gave me, and still nothing

I have no clue, it just stopped working? I think it may have
something to do with 'id' field, I don't know how that is generated or what the purpose of it is.  I set the 'id' to match 'user' and that doesn't help either.

Comment: Echo the query before executing it. Check if it has all the data it should.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got advice that should help you solve this problem, but what about the problem of when sessions expire?  If `loginStatus==1`, is there a cron job or something external to what you've posted that turns it back to 0 for inactive users?

I think a better way to achieve the same result would be to have each page load commit a "lastSeen" timestamp.  Then your list of "online" users consists of everyone whose "lastSeen" is within a configurable or programmable period, rather than those folks whose flag has not yet been reset to 0.